# Storing content of txt file in an array

Tags: java

I have a .txt file which looks like `43 78 63 73 99 ....`i.e., 
all its values are separated by spaces. 
I want each of them to be added into an array,such that 
`a[0]=43`
`a[1]='78`
`a[2]=63` and so on.
How can I do this in Java..Please explain

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into a string. Then spilt the string on the space into a string array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filereader to read in the values

E.g.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("yourFile.txt"));
```

Then you read all the integers from the file and put them into an integer array.

[Java Scanner class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

[Java File class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well I would do it by storing the text file into a string. (as long as it's not too big) Then I would just use .split(" ") to store it into an array.

Like this:

```
String contents = "12 32 53 23 36 43";
//pretend this reads from file

String[] a = contents.split(" ");
```

Now the array 'a' should have all the values stored in it. If you want the array to be an int, you could use an int array, and use Integer.toString() to convert data types.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class readTextToIntArray {
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/GoForce5500/Documents/num.txt"));
    String content;
    List<String> contentList=new ArrayList<String>();
    while((content=reader.readLine())!=null){
        for(String column:content.split(" ")) {
            contentList.add(column);
        }
    }
    int[] result=new int[contentList.size()];
    for(int x=0;x<contentList.size();x++){
        result[x]=Integer.parseInt(contentList.get(x));
    }
}
}
```

You may use this.

Comment: When helping beginners, it's typically best for you to provide an explanation instead of just posting code that compiles.